# SWIG-PHP / VS2013: Linker errors

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013, swig

Trying to run this STL example using `std::vector` from the documentation, but I am getting linker errors.

**example.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
double average(std::vector<int> v) {
  return std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0.0)/v.size();
}
std::vector<double> half(const std::vector<double>& v) {
  std::vector<double> w(v);
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<w.size(); i++)
    w[i] /= 2.0;
  return w;
}
void halve_in_place(std::vector<double>& v) {
  std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),v.begin(),
      std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(),2.0));
}
```

**example.i**

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
  %}
  %include "std_vector.i"
  // Instantiate templates used by example
  namespace std {
    %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
    %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
  }
// Include the header file with above prototypes
%include "example.h"
```

Because I'm using swig for a PHP extension, I run `swig -php -c++ example.i` to generate the appropriate wrapper. Compiling the sources gives

```
Warning 6   warning C4005: 'inline' : macro redefinition    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xkeycheck.h  203 1   swig_std_vector
Error   7   error C1189: #error :  The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing keywords. Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden macro.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\VC\include\xkeycheck.h 250 1   swig_std_vector
```

Adding `_XKEYCHECK_H` to the preprocessor directives opens up more errors:

```
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl std::_Atomic_compare_exchange_weak_4(unsigned long volatile *,unsigned long *,unsigned long,enum std::memory_order,enum std::memory_order)" (?_Atomic_compare_exchange_weak_4@std@@YAHPECKPEAKKW4memory_order@1@2@Z) C:\Users\Allan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\swig_std_vector\swig_std_vector\example_wrap.obj   swig_std_vector
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl std::_Atomic_fetch_sub_4(unsigned long volatile *,unsigned long,enum std::memory_order)" (?_Atomic_fetch_sub_4@std@@YAKPECKKW4memory_order@1@@Z)   C:\Users\Allan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\swig_std_vector\swig_std_vector\example_wrap.obj   swig_std_vector
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl std::_Atomic_load_4(unsigned long volatile *,enum std::memory_order)" (?_Atomic_load_4@std@@YAKPECKW4memory_order@1@@Z)    C:\Users\Allan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\swig_std_vector\swig_std_vector\example_wrap.obj   swig_std_vector
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl std::_Atomic_fetch_add_4(unsigned long volatile *,unsigned long,enum std::memory_order)" (?_Atomic_fetch_add_4@std@@YAKPECKKW4memory_order@1@@Z)   C:\Users\Allan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\swig_std_vector\swig_std_vector\example_wrap.obj   swig_std_vector
```

I can make simpler PHP extensions using SWIG that run ok, but they do not make use of the STL in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to define `ZEND_WIN32_FORCE_INLINE`.